# Falsy Freecodecamp algorithm challenge

Tags: javascript

This code is supposed to remove all falsy values from an array.
Am I close to getting it or should I scrap what I'm doing? I tend to get close only to give up later.

```
function bouncer(arr) {

var bouncer = arr.filter(function(bouncer)undefined, null, NaN, 0, "", false); return arr; } 

bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]);
```

Comment: Just use `arr.filter(e => e)`.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to filter by Boolean. That should work. You are overcomplicating the problem in my Opinion. Look at this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/gznskhme/). The `Boolean` Keyword is implemented in JS and simply checks if the given value is a valid Argument. Read more about the `Boolean` keyword [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_booleans.asp).

Instead of `alert` you could also use `return` or `console.log` or give the Values into a field on the Site like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gznskhme/3/).

Comment: I never noticed that the original challenge suggested that I use a Boolean. Thanks for the help.

Comment: yeah no problem. Glad to help somebody taking the same path as me. Good luck with those challenges.

Comment: @OriginalName, Kindly mark his / her answer accepted if you think this is helpful for your case: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, just advice...

If you're learning to code you should be writing your code so that it's obvious and clear (to you) what's happening. For example, here's some code that's a little pedantic but hopefully understandable:

```
function copy_truthies(in_values) {
  let out_values = [];

  in_values.forEach(value => {
    if (value) {
      out_values.push(value);
    }
  });

  return out_values;
}

let all_values = [7, "ate", "", false, 9];
let truthy_values = copy_truthies(all_values);
console.log(truthy_values);
```

Tushar's solution is idiomatic, elegant, and does the same thing; but it might not be immediately understood by someone just starting out:

```
console.log([7, "ate", "", false, 9].filter(e=>e))
```

Just give it a few months and you'll be thinking fluently in one-liners :)